# Parse.com Rest API, how to have a limit and query restraints in same url using curl

Tags: rest, curl, parse-platform

I'm struggling with knowing how to do the following. I want to do functionality similar to:

```
     --data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Jonathan Walsh"}' \
     --data-urlencode 'limit=100' \
```

but I would quite like to do this in one --data-urlencode request. Is this possible? And could someone show me what the url would look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will looks like:
`https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore?where={%22playerName%22:%22Jonathan%20Walsh%22}&limit=100`

Your another question is using one request, or one --data-urlencode?
FYI, you could use several --data-urlencode in one request.